# How to find geolocation of a photo in Linux?

Tags: linux, geolocation

I have taken some photos on my Ubuntu machine, and I'd like to know whether they contain geolocation, and if so, what are they.

How can I do that?

Comment: This depends on the software you used. What software _did_ you use?

Comment: Ever see this website (platform independent)? http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi *Note: you are uploading your photos to a third party, make sure you are OK with them being on the front page of the Sunday Times **before** uploading.*

Comment: Related, but on a different site, and not quite the same: [AskUbuntu: Command to see media file info in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249828/command-to-see-media-file-info-in-terminal).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`exiftool` can be used to print out the metadata of the image.  If the location was stored when the image was taken (usually called '[geotagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging)'), you can find it there:

```
$ exiftool 23.jpg  | grep GPS
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : East
GPS Latitude                    : 35 deg 32' 16.80" N
GPS Longitude                   : 139 deg 29' 49.20" E
GPS Position                    : 35 deg 32' 16.80" N, 139 deg 29' 49.20" E
$
```

You can also use exiftool to strip the GPS information out of an existing image:

```
$ exiftool -gps:all= 23.jpg
    1 image files updated
$ exiftool 23.jpg | grep GPS
$
```

Any tool that can look at image metadata can look at this information.  For example, the `identify` tool from ImageMagic will also do it:

```
$ identify -verbose 23.jpg | grep GPS
    exif:GPSInfo: 640
    exif:GPSLatitude: 35/1, 3228/100, 0/1
    exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
    exif:GPSLongitude: 139/1, 2982/100, 0/1
    exif:GPSLongitudeRef: E
$
```

and GUI tools can often do so as well - here's Image Viewer from Ubuntu 18:

[image: Image Viewer Details/Metadata]

Many images do not have GPS entries in their metadata - for example, if you take a picture with a camera that doesn't have GPS, it won't store it - here's a [list of cameras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cameras_which_provide_geotagging) that *do* have GPS.

Most cell phones, of course, have a GPS, and often will geotag by default.  You can choose to disable this in [Android](https://www.howtogeek.com/303410/how-to-prevent-android-from-geotagging-photos-with-your-location/) and [iPhones](https://www.techbout.com/turn-off-geotagging-for-photos-iphone-ipad-8738/).

Comment: Thanks. How can I install `exiftool` on Ubuntu?

Comment: @randon `sudo apt install exiftool` will install it for you.

Comment: There is some really helpful info on how to scan folders of images for geotags in [this brilliant thread at the exiftool forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=3075.0).

Answer (score 4):

This command will check your photos in a directory and looks up whether Geo tags are saved in Exif. It will report those where data was found:

```
for f in *.jpg; do CMD="$(exiftool -a -gps:all "$f" 2>/dev/null | grep "GPS Latitude")"; RET=$?; if [ "$RET" -eq "0" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

If you want to automatically parse the geo information in computer-readable format in order to further process the coordinates, you can use this

```
exiftool -c "%+.6f" "$1" |grep "GPS Position" | cut -d":" -f2 | tr -d ' '
```

This tool (bash script) does it automatically on the file that is passed to it as argument:
https://gist.github.com/pas-calc/0e6063affa749fedc2e51cea88345929 .
The results will be displayed on the [Geo Tool](http://geo.klein-computing.de/gpx_tool.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

In case your file manager is Nemo, then a pluggable action collection may help: https://github.com/s-n-ushakov/exif-gps-mapping-nemo .
It allows displaying Exif metadata of media files in popup windows in Nemo, as well as displaying shooting locations in OpenStreetMap, Google Maps or whatever. Screenshots are available there in README...